# git staging no whitespace

Tags: git, diff, staging, git-cola

I know about interactive staging (from a GUI point of view at least) and I know how to ignore whitespace changes in git diff with `git diff -w`.

I'm using git-cola at the moment and there is the option to hide whitespace changes on the diff view but then interactive staging doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to do interactive staging (line by line) while ignoring whitespace changes? If I have to go back to command line that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is just not possible in git-cola at least.
See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-cola/aMsHhWMSz_E